# Select from a table with different where clauses

Tags: sql, select

I have a table as

```
EmpAttendance

Date    EmpId Attendance
1/1/12   Emp1   P
1/1/12   Emp2   P
2/1/12   Emp1   P
2/1/12   Emp2   A
```

From this, I want a report showing total presents and absents of all the employees

```
AttendanceReport
EmpId    Presents    Absents
Emp1      2            0
Emp2      1            1
```

Help me Please

Comment: that's great. carry on

Comment: I think you might avoid the down-votes by saying in your q exactly what you've tried so far and posing an explicit question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the `empid` and the use a case to sum up only the presents and absents

```
select empid, 
       sum(case when attendance = 'P' then 1 end) as presents,
       sum(case when attendance = 'A' then 1 end) as absents
from EmpAttendance
group by empid
```